# Condición para checkbox

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

tengo el siguiente checkbox si se me guarda informacion en la base de datos, si selecciono los 3 no me da error, pero si selecciono 1 o 2 el o los faltantes no seleccionados me los marca como error ¿Que puedo hacer?

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
    $coberturas = $_POST["Coberturas"];
    $coberturas2 = $_POST["Coberturas2"];
    $coberturas3 = $_POST["Coberturas3"];
    
        
    if($cliente == 'X'){
        $cliente ='';
  
    }else{
       query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje,  
Coberturas, Coberturas2, Coberturas3 VALUES 
(DEFAULT, '".$coberturas."', '".$coberturas2."', '".$coberturas3."')");
       
}
}
?>
            
                            <form id="nclientes" name="nclientes" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                 
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Coberturas</h3>
                                    <div id="div1" class="col-sm-3">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas" value="ROT">Continuacion de Viaje<br>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas2" value="Riesgos">No Continuacion de Viaje 1<br>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas3" value="Contaminación">No Continuacion de Viaje 2
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Isaias, los campos de tu base de datos (Coberturas, Coberturas2, Coberturas3) permiten nulos?

Comment: No, es por eso? Le pongo que permita nulos?

Comment: el error se da porque en tu base de datos es obligatorio las 3 coberturas.

Comment: Entonces que puedo hacer?

Comment: edita los campos de tu BD y permitelos que sean nulos siempre que sea asi lo que requieres

Comment: Ya lo puse nulo pero igual sigue saliendome el mismo error si selecciono solo 2 el tercero me lo marca como variable no definida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php), para evitar los errores de variables no definidas (Notice: Undefined variable: my_variable_name in C:\wamp\www\mypath\index.php on line N). Asi como en tu base de datos debes hacer que acepten nulos los campos no requeridos.

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
    $coberturas =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Coberturas");
    $coberturas2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Coberturas2");
    $coberturas3 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Coberturas3");
    
        
    if($cliente == 'X'){
        $cliente ='';
  
    }else{
       query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje,  
Coberturas, Coberturas2, Coberturas3 VALUES 
(DEFAULT, '".$coberturas."', '".$coberturas2."', '".$coberturas3."')");
       
}
}
?>
            
                            <form id="nclientes" name="nclientes" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                 
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Coberturas</h3>
                                    <div id="div1" class="col-sm-3">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas" value="ROT">Continuacion de Viaje<br>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas2" value="Riesgos">No Continuacion de Viaje 1<br>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas3" value="Contaminación">No Continuacion de Viaje 2
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Ya puse los campos en la base de datos nulo y con el filter_input que me agregaste pero no me guarda los campos

Comment: Tal vez es porque no estas esté bien a la funcion "query()", no se si realizaste esta función en donde mandas llamar dentro de ella la función de mysqli_query(), si es que usas mysql, lo correcto sería ... mysqli_query($variableConexion, "INSERT INTO merca (idViaje,  
Coberturas, Coberturas2, Coberturas3 VALUES 
(DEFAULT, '".$coberturas."', '".$coberturas2."', '".$coberturas3."')");

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregarle a tu código esto:

```
if($_POST["coberturas"] == ''){
$coberturas = "relleno";
} else {};
if($_POST["coberturas2"] == ''){
$coberturas2 = "relleno";
} else{};
if($_POST["coberturas3"] ==  ''){
$coberturas3 = "relleno";
} else{};
```

Cualquier error gramatical pido disculpas, estoy del móvil.